# Headless chrome cli in Production

Tags: clojure, pdf-generation, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, chromeless

I will be doing some pdf generation for my application. Currently, my plan is to create HTML using templates and convert them to PDF.

The pdf's aren't long. Maximum 3 pages. And approximately we will be making approx 100 docs in a day.

I was happy with the results I got from `chrome --headless` in my local machine. I called the `cli` command directly from my clojure code. So far so good. Looking at the number of wrappers available (Browserless, Chromeless, Puppeteer, ...) I'm not sure about the scalability factor in production.

- Is it safe to use/call the chrome cli directly in production boxes?
- What will I miss if I skip these wrappers?

My server side stack is Clojure/Compojure/Leiningen. Any insights/alternatives are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detouring through html and chrome, I'd just use a pdf creating library such as [clj-pdf](https://github.com/clj-pdf/clj-pdf). Here is a nice [blog post](https://medium.com/magnetcoop/pdf-generation-with-clojure-thanks-to-dmitri-sotnikov-14ad4fcb4255) about it.

p.s. If you dont mind running a third program to generate the pdf, I would have used emacs with org-mode (or heck, even writing it in elisp altogether) ;)

Comment: You can find more info on clj-pdf at https://pragprog.com/book/dswdcloj2/web-development-with-clojure-second-edition

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Athena PDF for pdf generation in combination with Clojure:

https://github.com/arachnys/athenapdf

It has a REST interface. Since it runs in Docker its easy to scale.